# In Javascript is setTimeout blocking when embedded in a group of promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, settimeout

I have a function *func* that is largely composed of a number of promises, five promises in all.  In the third promise I have a very long setTimeout that could last as long as 3 days. If *func* is called more than once will it cue up additional requests and pass each one according to the setTimeout within the third promise or will it block other requests to the *func*?

Bonus - is a set up like this likely to cause other unforeseen consequences?

Comment: `setTimeout` never blocks.

Comment: …and it doesn't cue up automatically. You'd have to use `then` explicitly.

Comment: I understand what your saying but to be clear, if func is called and it pauses on the first call for 3 days because of the setTimeout within a promise, will it work when called a second time a minute later?  Assuming there are resources, will it work when called "N" times?

Comment: @rashadb: The point is that it doesn't "pause" anything. It just schedules some callback for later. Therefore, it does not influence any other calls (you can ignore resources).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is not blocking.  Calls to `.then` to chain callbacks for promises are blocking, but these should use up a tiny amount of CPU time. The answer to your question is that if you call `func` more than once, the function calls will effectively run in parallel even though they use `setTimeout` because it doesn't block.

Rather than just take my word for it, though, you can try running an example:

```
function run(timeout) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
}

run(10000).then(function () {
    console.log("10 second resolution");
});
run(3000).then(function () {
    console.log("3 second resolution");
});
run(1000).then(function () {
    console.log("1 second resolution");
});
```

This will print `1`, `3`, and `10` after approximately 1, 3, and 10 seconds, respectively, even though they were called in reverse order.